# rubber-banding multiple areas in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to display the image, then let the user create multiple rubber-band selections on the image. Each mouse-down creates an additional selection. Has anyone seen an implementation of this technique in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I did use this image cropper script. It uses a rubber band to select the crop area. The code is pretty simple to follow and you could probably modify it to do what you want. Selecting overlapping areas would probably be a bit of a challenge though.

Script: [JavaScript Image Cropper UI, using Prototype & script.aculo.us](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/)